# Pascal's Triangle - type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascals-triangle

So my code for some reason is giving me the error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

It has to do with the line:

```
answer = answer + combination(row, column) + "\t"
```

Here is my code:

```
def combination(n, k):
    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 1
    return combination(n - 1, k - 1) + combination(n - 1, k)

def pascals_triangle(rows):
    for row in range(rows):
        answer = ""
        for column in range(row + 1):
            answer = answer + combination(row, column) + "\t"
        print(answer)

pascals_triangle(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

In this line:

```
answer = answer + combination(row, column) + "\t"
         ^        ^                           
         |__ str  |__ int
```

`combination()` returns an `int`, and in Python you cannot do "str + int" implicitly, so convert it to `str` explicitly:

```
answer = answer + str(combination(row, column)) + "\t"
```

You may also avoid string concatenation for with something along:

```
answer = '{ans} {comb} \t'.format(ans=answer, comb=combination(row, column))
```

Answer (score 0):

Independent of the `str()` conversion issue that fixes your immediate problem, I'd like to touch on your algorithm for computing Pascal's triangle.  Your approach computes every row independently ignoring that the previous row calculated gives you a step up on the next.  Consider my (non-recursive) approach:

```
def pascals_triangle(rows):
    array = []

    for row in range(rows):
        array.append(1)  # both widens the row and initializes the last element

        for i in range(row - 1, 0, -1):  # fill in the row, right to left
            array[i] += array[i - 1]  # current computed from previous

        print(*array, sep="\t")
```

Bumping the rows from 10 to 25, on my system, this approach is ~ 400 times faster.  This is due to the *algorithm*, not *recursion*.  This same approach can be done both recursively and quickly:

```
def pascals_triangle(rows):
    array = [1]

    if rows > 1:
        array[0:0] = pascals_triangle(rows - 1)

        for i in range(rows - 2, 0, -1):  # fill in the row, right to left
            array[i] += array[i - 1]  # current computed from previous

    print(*array, sep="\t")
    return array  # return the last completed row
```